# fREAD a text file to count amount of name values - PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, count

I've created a form which users input numbers into, this data is then being written to a text file using fwrite.

Now my question is, is there a way to read the file in a sense, but only a certain post.. then count up how many of those have occurred, for example...

```
$data = sprintf("((%s,%s,%s))$s",
    $_POST['shapeType'],
    $_POST['circleRadius'],
    $_POST['circleColour'],
    PHP_EOL ); // automatically use the Operating System appropriate new line character sequence.
fwrite($handle, $data); }
fclose($handle);
?>
```

above is the fwrite, now 'shapeType' is circle on this specific write, is there a way to locate all the shapeType posts (other shapes like square etc..) therefore producing a

There are x amount of Shapes stored within the site.

x obviously replacing the counted amount, any ideas? im quite new to this so it may be impossible altogether.

update!! - what text file looks like

((Circle,120,Red))((Triangle,190,120,90,Blue))

((Circle,90,Blue))((Circle,20,Red))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each line of the file into an array and then loop through that array.  While you're looking at each line, just check to see if it matches 'circle' or whatever and if so, increment a counter.

```
<?php

$shape_type = $_POST['shapeType'];
$shape_counter = 0;

$lines = file($file_name);

foreach ($lines AS $line) {
    if (preg_match('/'.$shape_type.'/', $line)) {
        $shape_counter++;
    }
}

print "There are ".$shape_counter." amount of  ".$shape_type."s stored within the site.";
```

EDIT:

If you're just wanting to get the total number of lines, it's even easier.  Just do this:

```
<?php

$lines = file($file_name);

print "There are ".count($lines)." amount of shapes stored within the site.";
```

Comment: Is there any reason im getting 3 instead of 5 which there are stored?... where you have said shape_type i just want all shapeTypes to be considered the same. So it's shapes (yet its counts all the circles, triangles, squares etc...) if that makes sense

Comment: only 1 type of shape is increasing counter, the other one isnt, any idea?

Comment: Oh, so you just need to count the lines?  After you read the file into an array, just do this: `$line_count = count($lines);  print $line_count;`

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase this... i need to basically count everything stored in the text, for some reason 3 entries go in 1 line, then maybe only 2 in the other. ill update the main post to show you what it looks like (the text file)

Comment: Okay, so I see your edit. Basically you should have only one per line, separated by a newline. Try this instead of your `sprintf` statement: `$data = "((".$_POST['shapeType'].", ".$_POST['circleRadius'].", ".$_POST['circleColour']."))\n";` Then go into your text file and put each set on its own line. (Make sure you have a blank line at the end, since the newline is written after it writes its data.) Let me know if you need a solution for mapping these without the newlines. Like if you want to do it no matter how many items appear on one line. It's a little more involved, but still doable.